# How to create an image and div slide show using jquery?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

For a website I'm creating, I need a header which is consisted of two divs (left and right). 
The left one is an image slider and the right one is contained with information about the left picture (also an slider). The slide show must change in time intervals and also enable a user to select left and right. 
Can someone give me a sample code ?

Comment: Show us your code ... where are you facing problems or else this question doesn't make any sense asking like that ... we would like to see your code then only we can help !

Comment: You cant get a good answer the way your question is constructed. Anyway as far I can tell bxslider is a must for what you are going to do. http://bxslider.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is your sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/64hrq/

You can customize the slider with:

```
var slideInterval = 3000, // in milliseconds
```

and setting an array with your images url, like this:

```
imageArray = ["https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/256x256/Box_Green.png", "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/512/social_twitter_button_blue.png", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphics-vibe/simple-rounded-social/256/facebook-icon.png"];
```

and same thing with the relative text:

```
infoArray = ["image green text","twitter text","facebook text"];
```

Note that images and texts should be placed at the same index inside these two arrays. 
Ex:

```
imageArray ["img1", "img2"]; 
infoArray["text for img1", "text for img2"]
```